# magento2:unable to save the data in newly added column of sales_order_grid table

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento-2.0

trying to save the my oven data in newly added column of **sales_order_grid** but unable to to do so.

However, I can save my custom the data in **sales_order** table where I have added one extra column.
I am adding the data in **sales_order** table by getting below observer event.

```
$obj = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$obj->setMyName($value);
```

same data is not saving in **sales_order_grid** table having same column name..

is there there anyway or anything alternative to achieve this???

Comment: Do you call the `save()` method when trying to save ?

Comment: yes, I did but no luck.. as I told you its saving in sales_order table but in sales_order_grid table its not, where column name is same in the both table..
Am i taking wrong event ($observer->getEvent()->getOrder()) ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose column name 'delivery_date, So that you need to add di.xml for save some value for custom column to grid

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="string">sales_order.delivery_date</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

[Here is an example](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sohel Rana, I spend so much time to achieve this, you saved my time, thanks again.. However, I used different event (sales_order_place_after)

Comment: I have found you must run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` afterwards, then it starts to populate the grid column from the source table on insert/update.

Comment: Sir how can custom value save in custom_column in sales_order_grid table without populate from sales_order to sales_order_grid like your answer because my values are not in sales_order table ? 

i am using observer sales_model_service_quote_submit_before and now want to save value using model or have service contract for sales_order_grid ?