# Custom data saved in sales_order table but not saved in sales_order_grid table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales

Custom data saved in sales_order table but not saved in sales_order_grid table in magento 2

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="bootsgrid_order_custom_attributes" xsi:type="string">sales_order.bootsgrid_order_custom_attributes</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**sales_order** table

[image]

**sales_order_grid** table

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have checked this link:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/112891/59178

It worked for me :)